# Hash use array as key in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash that uses array as its key. When I change the array, the hash can no longer get the corresponding key and value:

```
1.9.3p194 :016 > a = [1, 2]
 => [1, 2] 
1.9.3p194 :017 > b = { a => 1 }
 => {[1, 2]=>1} 
1.9.3p194 :018 > b[a]
 => 1 
1.9.3p194 :019 > a.delete_at(1)
 => 2 
1.9.3p194 :020 > a
 => [1] 
1.9.3p194 :021 > b
 => {[1]=>1} 
1.9.3p194 :022 > b[a]
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :023 > b.keys.include? a
 => true
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update:
OK. Use a.clone is absolutely one way to deal with this problem. 
What if I want to change "a" but still use "a" to retrieve the corresponding value (since "a" is still one of the keys) ?

Comment: Here's another snippet to think about: http://pastie.org/4609694

Comment: weird! seems like a bug?

Answer (score 19):

The [#rehash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-rehash) method will recalculate the hash, so after the key changes do:

```
b.rehash
```

Comment: This method is what I want. Thank you!!

Comment: Although this may solve the OP's problem, there is a deeper issue at play. `#rehash` should never need calling to begin with. A need to call `#rehash` probably means there is something else wrong. There is another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36821695/361855 that talks about some better solutions.

Answer (score 9):

TL;DR: consider [`Hash#compare_by_indentity`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-compare_by_identity)

#### You need to decide if you want the hash to work by array *value* or array *identity*.

By default arrays `.hash` and `.eql?` by value, which is why changing the value confuses ruby.  Consider this variant of your example:

```
pry(main)> a = [1, 2]
pry(main)> a1 = [1]
pry(main)> a.hash
=> 4266217476190334055
pry(main)> a1.hash
=> -2618378812721208248
pry(main)> h = {a => '12', a1 => '1'}
=> {[1, 2]=>"12", [1]=>"1"}
pry(main)> h[a]
=> "12"
pry(main)> a.delete_at(1)
pry(main)> a
=> [1]
pry(main)> a == a1
=> true
pry(main)> a.hash
=> -2618378812721208248
pry(main)> h[a]
=> "1"
```

See what happened there?
As you discovered, it fails to match on the `a` key because the `.hash` value under which it stored it is outdated [BTW, you can't even rely on that!  A mutation might result in same hash (rare) or different hash that lands in the same bucket (not so rare).]

But instead of failing by returning `nil`, it matched on the `a1` key.
See, `h[a]` doesn't care at all about the *identity* of `a` vs `a1` (the traitor!).  It compared the current *value* you supply — `[1]` with the *value* of `a1` being `[1]` and found a match.

That's why **using `.rehash` is just band-aid**.  It will recompute the `.hash` values for all keys and move them to the correct buckets, but it's error-prone, and may also cause trouble:

```
pry(main)> h.rehash
=> {[1]=>"1"}
pry(main)> h
=> {[1]=>"1"}
```

Oh oh.  The two entries collapsed into one, since they now have the same value (and which wins is hard to predict).

#### Solutions

One sane approach is embracing lookup by value, which requires the value to never change.  `.freeze` your keys.  Or use `.clone`/`.dup` when building the hash, and feel free to mutate the original arrays — but accept that `h[a]` will lookup the current value of `a` against the values preserved from build time.

The other, which you seem to want, is deciding you care about identity — lookup by `a` should find `a` whatever its current value, and it shouldn't matter if many keys had or now have the same value.
How?

- `Object` hashes by identity.  (Arrays don't because types that `.==` by value tend to also override `.hash` and `.eql?` to be by value.)  So one option is: don't use arrays as keys, use some custom class (which may hold an array inside).
- But what if you want it to behave directly like a hash of arrays?  You could subclass Hash, or Array but it's a lot of work to make everything work consistently.  Luckily, Ruby has a builtin way: [`h.compare_by_identity`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-compare_by_identity) switches a hash to work by identity (with no way to undo, AFAICT).  If you do this before you insert anything, you can even have distinct keys with equal values, with no confusion:

  ```
  [39] pry(main)> x = [1]
  => [1]
  [40] pry(main)> y = [1]
  => [1]
  [41] pry(main)> h = Hash.new.compare_by_identity
  => {}
  [42] pry(main)> h[x] = 'x'
  => "x"
  [44] pry(main)> h[y] = 'y'
  => "y"
  [45] pry(main)> h
  => {[1]=>"x", [1]=>"y"}
  [46] pry(main)> x.push(7)
  => [1, 7]
  [47] pry(main)> y.push(7)
  => [1, 7]
  [48] pry(main)> h
  => {[1, 7]=>"x", [1, 7]=>"y"}
  [49] pry(main)> h[x]
  => "x"
  [50] pry(main)> h[y]
  => "y"
  ```

  Beware that such hashes [are counter-intuitive if you try to put there e.g. strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14305398/239657), because we're really used to strings hashing by value.

Answer (score 2):

Hashes use their key objects' hash codes (`a.hash`) to group them. Hash codes often depend on the state of the object; in this case, the hash code of `a` changes when an element has been removed from the array. Since the key has already been inserted into the hash, `a` is filed under its original hash code.

This means you can't retrieve the value for `a` in `b`, even though it looks alright when you print the hash.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `a.clone` as key

```
irb --> a = [1, 2]
==> [1, 2]

irb --> b = { a.clone => 1 }
==> {[1, 2]=>1}

irb --> b[a]
==> 1

irb --> a.delete_at(1)
==> 2

irb --> a
==> [1]

irb --> b
==> {[1, 2]=>1} # STILL UNCHANGED

irb --> b[a]
==> nil # Trivial, since a has changed

irb --> b.keys.include? a
==> false # Trivial, since a has changed
```

Using `a.clone` will make sure that the key is unchanged even when we change `a` later on.

Comment: How do you explain the original snippet? When `keys` contains `a`, but value can't be retrieved?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You are right. From that perspective, it's weird because `b.keys[0].object_id == a.object_id` returns `true` after deleting the key when `a` is used instead of `a.clone`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The reason for that is that the hash code `a.hash` is different after removing an element from the array, even if the object stays the same. This, the key can't be found anymore.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev When looking up a key in a hash, the hash code is being used - no luck in this case, because the code has changed since the insertion of the key. The `keys` property of the hash, however, is an array, and in array search the `equal?` method is used for equality testing. Thus, the value is found in the keys array.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already said, the trouble is that the hash key is the exact same object you later modify, meaning that the key changes during program execution.

To avoid this, make a copy of the array to use as a hash key:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = { a.clone => 1 }
```

Now you can continue to work with `a` and leave your hash keys intact.

Comment: I think, he *wants* to be able to modify arrays and still be able to retrieve the values using those modified versions. I might be wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want.  Can't I change "a" but still use "a" as a key?