# How does Hash’s compare_by_identity work?

Tags: ruby, hash

I first ran the below Part I of code and get the desired output, now just to play around it and to do some research I did Part II.

#### Part I

```
irb(main):001:0> h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200, :c => "c" }
=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200, :c=>"c"}
irb(main):002:0> h1["a"]
=> 100
irb(main):002:0> h1[:c]
=> "c"
```

#### Part II

```
irb(main):003:0> h1.compare_by_identity
=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200, :c=>"c"}
irb(main):004:0> h1.compare_by_identity?
=> true
irb(main):005:0> h1["a"]
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> h1[:c]
=> "c"
irb(main):007:0>
```

How does `h1["a"]` give different values in  Part I and Part II but not the same happened with `h1[:c]`?

I’m using Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [docs for `compare_by_identity`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-compare_by_identity) say this:

> Makes `hsh` compare its keys by their identity, i.e. it will consider exact same objects as same keys.

Normally, hash keys will be matched using `eql?`, but `compare_by_identity` will instead match them using `equal?` (which is roughly equivalent to comparing `object_id`s*). Since different instances of a string with the same value have different `object_id`s, it doesn’t match. However, symbols always have the same `object_id`, so it does continue to match.

```
hash = { 'a' => 'str a', 'b' => 'str b', :c => 'sym c' }
hash.compare_by_identity

hash.keys.map(&:object_id)      #=> [70179407935200, 70179407935180, 358408]
['a', 'b', :c].map(&:object_id) #=> [70179405705480, 70179405705460, 358408]

hash.keys.zip(['a', 'b', :c]).map { |pair| pair.inject(:eql?) }   #=> [true, true, true]
hash.keys.zip(['a', 'b', :c]).map { |pair| pair.inject(:equal?) } #=> [false, false, true]

a_key = hash.keys.first  #=> 'a'
hash['a']   #=> nil
hash[a_key] #=> 'str a'
hash[:c]    #=> 'sym c'
```

As you can see, the `object_id`s for the strings do not match the `object_id`s of the keys in the hash, but the symbol does. In fact, if you run `'a'.object_id` & `'b'.object_id` (or call `object_id` on any string) repeatedly, you will get a different value each time.

<sub>*The caveat here is that one could override `object_id`, but it will have no effect on the comparison since `equal?` doesn’t actually use `object_id`. Further, redefining `equal?` will change this, but doing so is not recommended explicitly in the Ruby docs.</sub>

Comment: I just finished up your explanations and `OMG` Its awesome!! Nice explanation once more I have to say.Now i got  clear concept on that!

Comment: why the object-id for `:c` is not changed? what logic behind it?

Comment: @RubyTheBang `Symbol`s with the same value are always the same object. Just the way they work. Same is true for `Fixnum`s, `true`, `false`, & `nil`.

Comment: This is wrong. `Hash` never uses `==` for equality. It uses either `eql?` or `equal?` depending on the setting of `compare_by_identity`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You’re correct, and I’ve updated my answer to reflect that—thanks! I think my error was mostly in glancing too quickly at the docs for `Object#eql?` which shows it as being the same as `equal?` and `==`, and wrongly ignoring that they are usually overridden separately.

Comment: I didn't understand `hash.keys.zip(['a', 'b', :c]).map { |pair| pair.inject(:eql?) }` and `hash.keys.zip(['a', 'b', :c]).map { |pair| pair.inject(:equal?) }` . why these 2 sentences are needed here? and why `:eql?` and `:equal?` used? please explain me if you can!

Comment: @VBSlover For those two, it pairs up the values in `hash.keys` and the passed array, then it calls `eql?`/`equal?` with that pair (in this case, the `map` could also be `.map { |a, b| a.eql? b }`, which may be clearer). It’s probably best to look at the intermediate values generated (i.e., look at what just the `zip` call returns). `eql?` & `equal?` are used for the reason I give in the answer: “Normally, hash keys will be matched using `eql?`, but `compare_by_identity` will instead match them using `equal?`”, so I compare the result of using each.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Not sure why does under `2.2.0` result of hash['a'] return `str a` instead of nil. [http://pastebin.com/t3Hhbr12](http://pastebin.com/t3Hhbr12)

Comment: @Viren I think something changed specifically with regard to Strings. I'll have to look into it later.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I think you're right:

`
h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200, :c => "c" }
h1["a"]        #=> 100
h1.compare_by_identity
h1.compare_by_identity? #=> true
h1["a".dup]    #=> nil  # different objects.
h1[:c]         #=> "c"  # same symbols are all same.
`
Ref: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Hash.html#method-i-compare_by_identity

Note the .dup